# line-height property is striked out both in normal and media query

Tags: css

In the console you can see `line-height` is striked out both in normal and mobile view, I couldn't find root cause of this problem.

There are only 2 places where I've used `line-height` property so no chance of getting overwritten as well.

[image]

**Computed Tab Results**

[image]

[image]

Comment: usually that's because there's some rule with better specificity that overrides that css property.. it's hard to say with such a small glance

Comment: _"I couldn't find root cause of this problem"_ - and much less can we, by looking at a mere screenshot only. But you could go onto the "Computed" tab, that will show you where the finally applied value for a property actually came from.

Comment: I've added "Computed" tab results but not understanding which property is overriding "line-height", how to debug such cases ?